# Software Updater: Broken Update UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: apt, ppa

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Following error is coming while updating through Software Updater.

```
The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04 ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/./Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, why do you have trusty/14.04 sources?  and I don't see anything useful there (http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home) so why did you add it?

Comment: Thanks, I was confused about removing this. Working fine after removing this repo